# Running a tracking script with Blender in the background

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

Im trying to run a script that when Blender is opening through the command line with this script it will track the clip it is being open with. I have a script that already opens the Blender file with the Clip loaded with the frame range that needs tracking. What I need now is to have the script in charge of tracking run with Blender in the background. This issue I am coming up with is obviously context, and I am not sure how to work around this to make the tracking happen.

The operations that need to be ran are for the clip editor area and are:

```
bpy.ops.clip.detect_features(placement='OUTSIDE_GPENCIL', threshold=0.5, distance=25)
bpy.ops.clip.track_markers(sequence=True)  
bpy.ops.clip.track_markers(sequence=True, backwards=True)
```

And for the sake of making sure the clip is being loaded in this script I load the video by:

```
bpy.ops.clip.open(directory="/Users/corwinsmith/Documents/scripts/", files=[{"name":"CollegeHumor Passes The Bechdel Test (All-Nighter).mp4", "name":"CollegeHumor Passes The Bechdel Test (All-Nighter).mp4"}], relative_path=True)
bpy.data.movieclips["CollegeHumor Passes The Bechdel Test (All-Nighter).mp4"].name
```

Comment: And if this is worded poorly and more explanation is needed please ask and I will answer. Thank you in advance for the help.